# How can I solve "Parse error. Primary expression expected."

Tags: javascript, error-handling, minify

JS minifier gives this error. What is the problem here exactly? It is in if block.

```
$('#start-input-from').on('change', ()=>{
        if (wizard?.data?.start) {
            wizard.data.start = null;
        }
        validateInputFromToForm(wizard);
    }
```

How can I make it disappear?

Comment: The minifier might not know about optional chaining. You could use `if (wizard && wizard.data && wixard.data.start)` like you would have before optional chaining was added.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was also trying the same method before you commented. Indeed your answer is correct. Till now, it stopped giving out the error message. Thank you.